# View .mkv in quicklook

Tags: quicklook

Is there any plugin (or other way), to add support for `mkv` files in quicklook? In my searches, the way I found of doing it involves installing perian, which I’d really prefer not to do for a number of reasons, one of them being that it’s [no longer in development](http://perian.org/).

Answer (score 3):

A quick search turned up QLVideo, which I've now installed. It provides limited functionality with mkv (as well as avi, flv, asf, and a few others) including preview screen shots in QuickLook and thumbnails in Finder's GetInfo window. Unfortunately it does not actually play the video.

https://github.com/Marginal/QLVideo/releases/tag/rel-172

Sadly, Perian (a brilliant piece of software that I miss dearly) does not work with Apple's new replacement for the QuickTime infrastructure in MacOS.

Comment: It looks like a promising step in the right direction. Its first commit was 9 months after I’ve opened this question. Unfortunately, like you mention, it does not play the video.